# Subset a dataframe where number of matching variable is k

Tags: r, variables, subset, matching

I want to subset my dataframe under the condition that the number of matching variable is equal to a number, for instance

```
example <- rbind(sample(letters[1:5]),
             sample(letters[1:5]),
             sample(letters[1:5]),
             sample(letters[1:5]),
             sample(letters[1:5]))


example

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] "b"  "a"  "d"  "e"  "c" 
[2,] "e"  "c"  "a"  "d"  "b" 
[3,] "c"  "a"  "d"  "b"  "e" 
[4,] "b"  "d"  "e"  "c"  "a" 
[5,] "b"  "c"  "e"  "d"  "a"
```

if i wanted to my number of matching variables was 3, the two last rows would be selected, since they have 3 letter in common (same place and same letter).

Comment: Every row in the matrix should be compared to every other row in the matrix and if it matches the threshold (here 3) for any row then both the rows would be selected ?

Comment: Exactly, the rows that have 3 elements in common should be selected.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a reproducible data

```
set.seed(47)
example <- rbind(sample(letters[1:5]),
                 sample(letters[1:5]),
                 sample(letters[1:5]),
                 sample(letters[1:5]),
                 sample(letters[1:5]))

example
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,] "e"  "b"  "c"  "d"  "a" 
#[2,] "d"  "b"  "e"  "c"  "a" 
#[3,] "a"  "c"  "e"  "b"  "d" 
#[4,] "e"  "b"  "a"  "c"  "d" 
#[5,] "a"  "c"  "b"  "e"  "d"
```

One approach I could think of is by using double-looping

```
n <- 3
example[sapply(apply(example, 1, function(x) 
                     which(colSums(x == t(example)) >= n)), length) > 1, ]


#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,] "a"  "c"  "e"  "b"  "d" 
#[2,] "a"  "c"  "b"  "e"  "d"
```

Here, we compare each row with every other row, element wise and count the number of equal comparisons if it is equal or greater than the threshold (`n`). The other loop is to filter out the rows which are equal to itself.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use `combn` twice, first to enumerate the pairs and second to perform the pairwise comparisons.

Using ronak-shah's example,

```
combn(seq_len(nrow(example)), 2)[, combn(seq_len(nrow(example)), 2,
                                 FUN=function(x) sum(example[x[1],] == example[x[2],]) >= 3)]
[1] 3 5
```

which indicates the rows to keep.

This will often return a matrix and the set of rows may be repeated. For example, setting the threshold to 2, we get

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    2    3
[2,]    2    4    4    5
```

to get this into something useful, use `c` to turn the result into a vector and then `unique` to drop repeated rows. While we are at it, we may as well wrap the whole thing into a function that will allow the selection of threshold.

```
rowKeeper <- function(myMat, thresh) {
   myMat[unique(c(combn(seq_len(nrow(myMat)), 2)[,
         combn(seq_len(nrow(example)), 2,
               FUN=function(x) sum(myMat[x[1],] == myMat[x[2],]) >= thresh)])),]
}
```

Then try it out

```
rowKeeper(example, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] "a"  "c"  "e"  "b"  "d" 
[2,] "a"  "c"  "b"  "e"  "d"
```